# Rust threadpool gathering results

Tags: multithreading, rust, threadpool

I just picked up Rust because I have to do some file processing that requires speed.

I wrote the code, but now it's time to make it run in parallel. I have a problem with utilizing a thread pool in Rust. I found an implementation in rayon and decided to try it. However, the parallel code runs slower than the serial one.

I've created an example, it's much simpler:

```rs
use std::time::Instant;
use std::{thread, time};

fn do_stuff(i: u64) -> u64 {
    let seconds = time::Duration::from_secs(i);
    thread::sleep(seconds);
    println!("{:?}", i);
    return i * i;
}

fn parallel() {
    let mut x = Vec::new();

    let pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(8)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    for i in 1..10 {
        pool.install(|| {
            let result = do_stuff(i);
            x.push(result);
        });
    }

    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn serial() {
    let mut x = Vec::new();

    for i in 1..10 {
        let result = do_stuff(i);
        x.push(result);
    }

    println!("{:?}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    serial();
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed (serial): {:.2}s", duration.as_secs_f64());

    let start = Instant::now();
    parallel();
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed (parallel): {:.2}s", duration.as_secs_f64());
}
```

The results are:

```bash
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Time elapsed (serial): 45.00s
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Time elapsed (parallel): 45.01s
```

Here, the times are the same, but when running my actual code, the parallel version is much slower (i.e. 30s vs 50s - so I don't think this is about the thread creation overhead).

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is:

- I have an iterable of many elements (here it's 9, but it doesn't matter)
- I want to iterate over it, passing each element to a time-consuming function calculating stuff
- this function returns a result and I want to append it to a vector defined before launching the threads
- and I want to do it in a thread pool (I don't want to spawn a separate thread for each element)

So, pretty simple. I'm coming from Python, where doing something like `ProcessPoolExecutor` that returns results to a single list is really simple. Here however, I see no improvement from adding the thread pool.

Am I using it wrong? Is there a way to do it in Rust?

P.S I'm not sure I understand why I'm able to `.push` to `x` vector here in the `parallel` function. I mean, it looks like it's not thread safe.

Comment: You have to use `join`, `scope`, or parallel iterators within the `op` given to [`install`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/struct.ThreadPool.html#method.install) else you've just written linear code with extra steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this way more complicated than it is.

`rayon` already takes care of everything, no need to create a fancy threadpool or similar. Simply use parallel iterators. It will execute inside of the global `rayon` threadpool, which is automatically sized to the number of cores your system has.

```rust
fn parallel() {
    let x: Vec<u64> = (1..10).into_par_iter().map(do_stuff).collect();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

```
...
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Time elapsed (serial): 45.11s
...
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Time elapsed (parallel): 14.04s
```

If you **must** use a custom threadpool for some reason, don't use `install()` for every single element. `install()` doesn't run in parallel - it only returns once the function is finished.

Instead, enter the threadpool context with `install` and then `scope`+`spawn` inside of it.

I tried to stay close to your example with this one; note the added `Mutex` around `Vec`, because if you **actually** run things in parallel, you cannot just simply access the `Vec` from all threads simultaneously. (and with that I don't mean you shouldn't; I mean it is impossible without the use of `unsafe`. the compiler won't let you.)

```rust
fn parallel() {
    let x = Mutex::new(Vec::new());

    let pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(8)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    pool.install(|| {
        rayon::scope(|s| {
            for i in 1..10 {
                let x = &x;
                s.spawn(move |_| {
                    let result = do_stuff(i);
                    x.lock().unwrap().push(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    println!("{:?}", x.lock().unwrap());
}
```

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 81, 64]
Time elapsed (parallel): 9.05s
```

Of course this one can also be written much simpler via parallel iterators:

```
fn parallel() {
    let pool = rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(8)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let x: Vec<u64> = pool.install(|| (1..10).into_par_iter().map(do_stuff).collect());

    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Time elapsed (parallel): 10.03s
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! My habits from other languages made me completely blind to the way this should be done. I made it as you suggested, it works!

Comment: @dabljues That's what a lot of people struggle with when they switch to Rust. But in the end, many patterns other languages force us into are actually bad patterns; so I hope you power through the frustration and grow as a programmer, learning something in the process :)